# ¿Como visualizar los marcadore de Google Maps una vez genrado el APK?

Tags: java, android-studio

vengo con un detalle que me ha ocurrido,la cuestión es lo siguiente:

1. Tengo terminado una aplicación,  desde android studio lo he compilado varias veces haciendo pruebas y todo bien, me voy a enforcar en especial a un modulo que es de ubicación con marcadores y se muestra correcto sin problemas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Género mi apk y lo pruebo en dos celulares y si se instala bien todo el proceso, pero al momento de irme al modulo de ubicación y doy en clic en uno de los CardView no me muestra el mapa ni los marcadores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es que pudiera ser que algo hice mal o me este faltando al momento de generar mi APK.

**ubicaciones**

```
 @Override
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

       StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                String sucess = jsonObject.getString("success");
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("t_centroacopio_edomex");

                if (sucess.equals("1")){
                    for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        latitude = Double.parseDouble(object.get("latitude").toString());
                        longitude = Double.parseDouble(object.get("longitude").toString());

                        if (i == 0){
                            LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 10));
                        }
                        String name = (String) object.get("nombre");
                        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(name)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.centroacopio)).anchor(0.0f,0.0f);
                                //.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                        mMap.addMarker(marker);

                    }
                }

            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(C_AEdomex.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

**Debug**

```
 <resources>
  <!--
TODO: Before you run your application, you need a Google Maps API key.

To get one, follow this link, follow the directions and press "Create" at the end:
You can also add your credentials to an existing key, using these values:

Package name:
com.hdez.logishuman

SHA-1 certificate fingerprint:
34:77:AB:FD:DA:26:F4:F2:19:59:24:FD:CD:AE:17:B5:0D:76:44:D2

Alternatively, follow the directions here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get-key

Once you have your key (it starts with "AIza"), replace the "google_maps_key"
string in this file.
-->
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">
    AIzaSyBnWflgj8hqw4d5aRArs4irPVZruISUgIU
</string>
</resources>
```

**release**

```
 <resources>
  <!--
TODO: Before you release your application, you need a Google Maps API key.

To do this, you can either add your release key credentials to your existing
key, or create a new key.

Note that this file specifies the API key for the release build target.
If you have previously set up a key for the debug target with the debug signing certificate,
you will also need to set up a key for your release certificate.

Follow the directions here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/signup

Once you have your key (it starts with "AIza"), replace the "google_maps_key"
string in this file.
-->
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false"> AIzaSyBnWflgj8hqw4d5aRArs4irPVZruISUgIU</string>
 </resources>
```

Comment: El problema tiene una solución sencilla, aporta más información, por ejemplo: como configuras el mapa para que aparezca y cuando subes tu apk a playstore que configuración realizas para la api de google maps.

Comment: @Jorgesys no la he subido al playStore solo se los he mandado a algunas personas para que lo instalen y verifiquen su funcionamiento, ya edite mi pregunta.

Comment: @Jorgesys ya investigue un poco el key solo lo tengo como debug y debo tambien agregar como producción para los que quieran usarlo, no si se este en lo cierto.

Comment: Si, debes agregar ambas para asegurar que funcione cuando la subas desde android studio y también cuando la subas a Google Play, agregué una respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso como comentas, el problema es que al subir tu app a Google Play, esta app debe ser firmada con un certificado diferente al usado cuando subimos directamente las apps desde Android Studio.

[image: Jorgesys google maps]

Debes obtener el SHA-1 del certificado con el que firmaste tu app para Google Play y configurarlo en la consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Actualización:

De acuerdo al mensaje que obtuviste:

```
<resources>
  <!--
TODO: Before you release your application, you need a Google Maps API key.

To do this, you can either add your release key credentials to your existing
key, or create a new key.

Note that this file specifies the API key for the release build target.
If you have previously set up a key for the debug target with the debug signing certificate,
you will also need to set up a key for your release certificate.

Follow the directions here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/signup

Once you have your key (it starts with "AIza"), replace the "google_maps_key"
string in this file.
-->
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false"> AIzaSyBnWflgj8hqw4d5aRArs4irPVZruISUgIU</string>
 </resources>
```

Te indica la forma para configurar tu API Key en tu aplicación, dentro de tu archivo `strings.xml` agrega:

```
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">AIzaSyBnWflgj8hqw4d5aRArs4irPVZruISUgIU</string>
```

y dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` haz referencia a la API Key:

```
   <application>
      ...
      ...
     <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
       android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
   
   </application>
```

Muy importante revisar que en https://console.cloud.google.com la API Key del proyecto que usas, tenga habilitada la API:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya coloque en ambas el Api Key, pero en el release no tengo certificado, dices que debe de ser diferente certificado en ambas, volví editar mi pregunta

Comment: @Miguel gracias Miguel, revisa la actualización de mi respuesta.

Comment: Si lo tengo así tal como tu respuesta, tal vez el detalle es que no lo he subido a la play store todavia, lo primero que estaba haciendo es generar el apk como lanzamiento pero lo estaba instalando primero a mi celular para hacer pruebas es ahi donde donde no visualizo los mapas, no si primero tengo que subir mi apk al play store y el problema se resuelva, y por otra parte mejor genere la apk de modo debug ya que lo quiero para mandárselo a otros compañeros para que realicen pruebas del funcionamiento, y es así como por lo pronto funcionan los mapas.

Comment: " el detalle es que no lo he subido a la Play Store todavia", puedes subirlo como "alpha" o "beta" testing para probar ya desde la Play Store, incluso puedes compartir el url a tus compañeros. Cuando todo esté correcto, puedes promover esta publicación a producción ya para todos tus usuarios.

Comment: Ok amigo, tomare en cuenta eso de subirlo como beta, gracias por tu apoyo.

Comment: Por cierto, muy importante revisar que en https://console.cloud.google.com la API Key del proyecto que usas, tenga habilitada la API "Maps SDK for Android"